# Xcode: When I load my app onto a simulator or device, nothing is appearing in the tableViewCells

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

Here is what I see on the storyboard. You can see the attributes of my table on the right:

[image]

Here is what I'm seeing after I launch the app:

[image]

I have not written any code that changes the view. It's all here in the storyboard. Everything is visible except the cells.

Comment: is your dark mode on ?

Comment: No, It's on light mode.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps you

Comment: hello @Dr.Taco solved this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode actually let you compile and run app with a `tableview` inside a UIViewController but  It will show a blank table .. So instead of `UIViewController` embed static cell in `UITableViewController` . You can use `ContainerView` to get a static `UITableView` along with other controls on the same screen .. Embed tableViewController in `containerView`

Ray Wenderlich's website [Blog Post](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3003-beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2) says

> One more thing about static cells, they only work in
>   UITableViewController. The Storyboard Editor will let you add them to
>   a Table View object inside a regular UIViewController, but this won’t
>   work during runtime. The reason for this is that UITableViewController
>   provides some extra magic to take care of the data source for the
>   static cells. Xcode even prevents you from compiling such a project
>   with the error message: “Illegal Configuration: Static table views are
>   only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances”.

.